# how to handle system wide key events in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, activex

i am working on an asp.net web application, where tasks are assigned to users, we set standard time to every task, in that standard time period the user has to finish the task, there are two buttons on the page, proceed and save, when a user clicks on proceed button, the time is saved in database as starttime, and when the user clicks on save button, the time is saved in database as endtime. this way we are capturing the time period within which the user is completing the task.

the standard time is set on an average time study basis, not every time the task takes the same amount of time.

often users can complete the task in very less time than the standard time, in this case the users are proceeding the task and even after completing the task, instead of saving it, they lock the system and go for tea breaks and after coming from break, they save the task.

i want to save some information on the web page when they lock the pc even when the browser is minimized.

i tried implementing applet using jintellitype library but its not capturing the key combinations that are used by windows os.

i also tried using Silverlight but there is no such support as in winforms application in Silverlight, i have to create a com component or something that interacts with system32 or some native api. it doesn't seem easy for me, i would like to know if there is such library for Silverlight.

it should be browser independent, i haven't tried ActiveX, but i think it can be done using ActiveX, but i don't want to use ActiveX as it runs only on IE.

i want to know all the possible solutions to achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you set a kind of timer-check to know if the last time is too far from the correspondent (and previewed) time to perform the job? If a task may expend, for instance, from 1 to 5 minutes, have 21 minutes is too far.

Why din´t you create a timer to TIMEOUT user? If users know they will be timed-out after some time, probably, they won´t leave to coffre-break during the test (a kind of penalty must be aggregated on this, like start from the initial point if timeout).

Why don´t you automatically save the record after the job finish, instead obly the user to press a button?

Until I know, you can perform SUSPEND mode, but not detect them if started from other apps.

Comment: thanks @David,   actually they do tasks on other apps, in this app we are just saving the time period they spent on other apps, they open two browsers side by side, as soon as they start the task, they click the proceed button in my app, and when they finish the task, they save it.

Comment: I understood... If you have a time to save the last 120 seconds in a kind of carrousell-array of strings/time, you could detect (and discard by math) the time spent outside computer. I mean, you will have readings by second (120 readings of 1 second elapsed each one of other) and you can compare the last 10 readings - you will detect the abnormal elapsed time between the last 2 ou 3...  Something like a watchdog. Having that abnormal lapse, you can subtract it from the total-time spent on task.